# Why Request.Headers["X-PJAX"] is always empty when implementing pjax in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, pjax

I am trying to implement pjax in asp.net core but `Request.Headers["X-PJAX"]` is always empty. PJAX docs are - https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

My _Layout.cs html code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // pjax
        $('ul a').pjax('#main')
    })
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/" class="current">MAIN PAGE</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="main">@RenderBody()</div>
</body>
```

My _ViewStart.cshtml page code:

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.PJAX==true)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

MY controller's index and about action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["X-PJAX"]))
            ViewBag.PJAX = false;
        else
            ViewBag.PJAX = true;
        return View();
    }

public IActionResult About()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["X-PJAX"]))
            ViewBag.PJAX = false;
        else
            ViewBag.PJAX = true;
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is I get `Request.Headers["X-PJAX"]` always ""? Why???

Please help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're selecting an empty container for Pjax . Let's inspect your HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="current">MAIN PAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="main">@RenderBody()</div>
</body>
```

and you're initializing `pjax` as below :

```
$('ul a').pjax('#main')
```

Note the `#main` is not a child of `ul`.

To fix your code, simply try:

```
$(document).pjax('#main')
```

Or if you would like to custom the selectors, try the following examples:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#main')
$(document).pjax('ul a', '#main')
```

Comment: thank you itminus. It solved my problem. However now the action methods are called not one but 2 times whenever the link is clicked. Why it is happening?

Comment: @yogihosting Sounds like it triggers the event twice. Could you please show me the complete code?

Comment: I added all the codes to the question now. Have a look please.

Comment: @yogihosting Possible reason: a short timeout cause to canceling. Could you please add a much longer timeout by : ` $(document).pjax("a",'#main',{ timeout: 4000})` ?

Comment: I added the timout to 10000 but it did not helped.

Comment: @yogihosting Did you invoke `pjax()` twice?  I'm asking that because I test your code, and using a much longer timeout works fine for me. Or could you please show us how did you invoke the `Pjax`?

Comment: I did not invoked it twice. There is only one code '$(document).pjax('#main')' that is invoking pjax. Can you add your full pjax application code in github and provide me the link to it. Thanks

Comment: @yogihosting I've pushed my local code to [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/newbienewbie/SO-54266725-Demo) . If you have any further questions, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: thank you your repository worked correctly. With your help I am able to get the proper solution of pjax. I found out that the action method should return a partial view for pjax to work. If they return a normal view then pjax will fail. Thank you once again.

Comment: thank you your repository worked correctly. With your help I am able to get the proper solution of pjax. I found out that the action method should return a partial view for pjax to work. If they return a normal view then pjax will fail. Thank you once again.